# Adding constraints to my searchable.xml

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, android-search

I am using the following xml file to implement auto-suggest for my SearchView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/find_contact"
android:hint="@string/find_contact"
android:gravity="center"
android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
android:queryAfterZeroResults="true"
android:searchMode="queryRewriteFromText"
android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/find_contact"
android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.android.contacts"
android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.provider.Contacts.SEARCH_SUGGESTION_CLICKED"
android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup" >

<!-- allow green action key for search-bar and per-suggestion clicks -->
<actionkey
    android:keycode="KEYCODE_CALL"
    android:queryActionMsg="call"
    android:suggestActionMsg="call" />

</searchable>
```

The problem is, along with suggesting valid contacts, it provides suggestion of email ids in contacts and other "bogus" contacts.

**I want to add a constraint to give suggestions only for valid phone contacts, that is contacts that have a phone number.**

How to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the only way is to extend a ContentProvider for querying the ContactProvider for the desired entities and to assign it in your searchable.xml as your searchSuggestAuthority.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

The ContactsContract.Contacts class also contains the HAS_PHONE_NUMBER column so you can query the Contacts provider by filtering on that field with something like this:

```
context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contact.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contact._ID}, ContactsContract.Contact.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=?", new String[]{"1"}, null), true);
```

I didn't checked the code before but i hope i'm giving some good tip ;)